# Счет количества переходов через отметку. Зависает Excel при выполнении макроса

Tags: excel, vba

Здравствуйте

Появились проблемы с макросом - при его выполнении стал зависать Excel.

Суть - при выполнении кода должно записываться количество переходов через отметку "-3" в выделенном диапазоне на скриншоте.

Помощь будет очень кстати!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
For j = 23 To 24
  i = 24
  k = 0
  Do While i < 55
    If Cells(i - 1, j).Value < -3 Then
      If Cells(i, j).Value > -3 Then
        k = k + 1
        i = i + 1
      End If
      i = i + 1
    End If
  Loop
  Cells(i, j + 7).Value = k
Next j



End Sub
```

[image: Данные]

Comment: Трассировка и окно локальных переменных в помощь... Ну или просто отформатировать код - и сразу видно, что не в том месте расположен оператор инкремента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш цикл (То, что в теле *If*, можно не рассматривать)

```
Do While i < 55
    If Cells(i - 1, j).Value < -3 Then

    End If
Loop
```

Читаем: если условие *If* не выполняется, цикл повторяется. Т.к. значение переменной i не меняется, получаем бесконечное зацикливание.

Правильно: *i = i + 1* вынести из тела *If* и записать перед строкой *Loop*.

Еще ошибка - в коде проверяется только переход через границу вверх. Пересечение сверху вниз не проверяется.

Вариант.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim bFlag As Boolean
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    For j = 23 To 24
        k = 0: bFlag = False
        If Cells(24, j).Value > -3 Then bFlag = True

        For i = 25 To 55
            If bFlag = True Then
                If Cells(i, j).Value < -3 Then bFlag = False: k = k + 1
            Else
                If Cells(i, j).Value > -3 Then bFlag = True: k = k + 1
            End If   
        Next i

        Cells(55, j + 7).Value = k
    Next j
End Sub
```

Можно добавить константу и при необходимости оперативно менять границу:

```
Const dBord As Double = -3
```

Если диапазон большой, лучше обрабатывать в массиве.

Попутно: переменные типа *Long* занимают больше места в памяти, но обрабатываются быстрее, чем *Integer*, т.к. не требуют преобразования.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка здесь:

```
If Cells(i - 1, j).Value < -3 Then
  If Cells(i, j).Value > -3 Then
    k = k + 1
    i = i + 1
  End If
  i = i + 1
End If
```

Так как начальные значения для `i` и `j` 24 и 23, обе условия в `If` неверные и значениe `i` никогда не изменится - и так внешний цикл

```
Do While i < 55
```

побежит бесконечно раз.

Вы наверно хотели это:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

For j = 23 To 24
  k = 0
  For i = 24 To 54
    If (Cells(i - 1, j).Value < -3) And (Cells(i, j).Value > -3) Or _
       (Cells(i - 1, j).Value > -3) And (Cells(i, j).Value < -3) Then
          k = k + 1
    End If
  Next i
  Cells(55, j + 7).Value = k          ' *** Измените, когда вы хотите што-то другое ***
Next j

End Sub
```